# Javascript factory pattern with a default, not working

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern

In school I had to make a Javascript script using Javascript's Factory Pattern Design, that "made" pizzas.
The Factory function had to receive 3 arguments (an array of strings for the ingredients, the price of the pizza, and a string for the price), and if an argument was missing it had to return a default Pepperoni Pizza.

I used this code:

```js
function pizzaFactory(ing, pric, siz) {
    let ingred = null;
    let price = null;
    let size = null;
    if(typeof ing == "undefined" || typeof pric == "undefined" || typeof siz == "undefined") {
        ingred = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "tomato sauce", "lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of love"];
        price = 125;
        size = "Small";
    } else {
        ingred = ing;
        price = pric;
        size = siz;
    }
    return {
        ing: ingred,
        pric: price,
        siz: size,
        deliver: function() {
            console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ing}`);
            console.log(`Price: ${pric}`);
            console.log(`Size: ${siz}`);
        }
    };
}
let ingredients = ['cheese', 'tomato sauce', 'hate'];
const pizza1 = pizzaFactory(ingredients, 150, "Large");
pizza1.deliver();
const pizza2 = pizzaFactory();
pizza2.deliver();
```

The problem is that the function only works when passing all arguments, and although the function enters the `if` and assigns correctly the value to the variables `ingred`, `price` and `size`. When running the `deliver` function the values appear as undefined.

I was wondering what's the problem with my code, and if there's a better/more effective way for doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the function, the input arguments are named `ing`, `pric`, and `siz`. Then, the *validated* values are put into the variables `ingred`, `price`, and `size`.

Currently, in the returned object, you're referencing `ing`, `pric`, and `siz`, rather than the validated variables - fix that, and it works as intended:

```js
function pizzaFactory(ing, pric, siz) {
    let ingred = null;
    let price = null;
    let size = null;
    if(typeof ing == "undefined" || typeof pric == "undefined" || typeof siz == "undefined") {
        ingred = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "tomato sauce", "lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of love"];
        price = 125;
        size = "Small";
    } else {
        ingred = ing;
        price = pric;
        size = siz;
    }
    return {
        ing: ingred,
        pric: price,
        siz: size,
        deliver: function() {
            console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ingred}`);
            console.log(`Price: ${price}`);
            console.log(`Size: ${size}`);
        }
    };
}
let ingredients = ['cheese', 'tomato sauce', 'hate'];
const pizza1 = pizzaFactory(ingredients, 150, "Large");
pizza1.deliver();
const pizza2 = pizzaFactory();
pizza2.deliver();
```

This is one reason why precise variable names are important. You might consider using different ones, to make the difference clear: for example, maybe `ingredArg` and `ingredValidated`:

```js
function pizzaFactory(ingArg, pricArg, sizArg) {
    const argsValid = [ingArg, pricArg, sizArg].every(arg => arg !== undefined)
    const ingredValidated = argsValid ? ingArg : ["pepperoni", "cheese", "tomato sauce", "lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of love"];
    const priceValidated = argsValid ? pricArg : 125; 
    const sizeValidated = argsValid ? sizArg : 'Small';
    return {
        ing: ingredValidated,
        pric: priceValidated,
        siz: sizeValidated,
        deliver: function() {
            console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ingredValidated}`);
            console.log(`Price: ${priceValidated}`);
            console.log(`Size: ${sizeValidated}`);
        }
    };
}
let ingredients = ['cheese', 'tomato sauce', 'hate'];
const pizza1 = pizzaFactory(ingredients, 150, "Large");
pizza1.deliver();
const pizza2 = pizzaFactory();
pizza2.deliver();
```

Comment: So I don't need the `ing`, `pric` and `siz` variables in the returned object?

Comment: No, because (in your original code), those refer to the *original, unmodified arguments*, which may be `undefined` - rather, you want the values *after* they've been validated or populated with the default values, which are in the variable names `ingred`, `price`, and `size`.

Answer (score 0):

Order seems to be one entity, rather than creating different variables make a one order object and return it if you want.

```
function pizzaFactory(ing, pric, siz) {
  let order = {
    ing: null,
    pric: null,
    siz: null
  };

  if(!ing || !pric || !siz) {
    order = {
      ing: ["pepperoni", "cheese", "tomato sauce", "lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of love"],
      pric: 125,
      siz: 'Small'
    }
   } else {
    order = {
      ing,
      pric,
      siz
    }
  }
    return {
      ...order,
      deliver() {
        console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${order.ing}`);
        console.log(`Price: ${order.pric}`);          
        console.log(`Size: ${order.siz}`);
      }
    };
  }

let ingredients = ['cheese', 'tomato sauce', 'hate'];
const pizza1 = pizzaFactory(ingredients, 150, "Large");
pizza1.deliver();
const pizza2 = pizzaFactory();
pizza2.deliver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working solution for your problem:

```
function pizzaFactory(ing, pric, siz) {
    let ingred = null;
    let price = null;
    let size = null;
    if(typeof ing == "undefined" || typeof pric == "undefined" || typeof siz == "undefined") {
        ingred = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "tomato sauce", "lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of love"];
        price = 125;
        size = "Small";
    } else {
        ingred = ing;
        price = pric;
        size = siz;
    }
    return {
        ing: ingred,
        pric: price,
        siz: size,
        deliver: function() {
            console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ingred}`);
            console.log(`Price: ${price}`);
            console.log(`Size: ${size}`);
        }
    };
}
```

The only piece in your code which needs an update is following:

```
 return {
            ing: ingred,
            pric: price,
            siz: size,
            deliver: function() {
                console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ingred}`);
                console.log(`Price: ${price}`);
                console.log(`Size: ${size}`);
            }
        };
```

Where you need to update following statements:

```
console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ing}`);
```

To

```
console.log(`Pizza Ingredients: ${ingred}`);
```

Then,

```
console.log(`Price: ${pric}`);
```

To

```
console.log(`Price: ${price}`);
```

Then,

```
console.log(`Size: ${siz}`);
```

To

```
console.log(`Size: ${size}`);
```

As you were actually referring `ing`, `pric`, `siz` which are function arguments, and has to be `undefined` when you are calling function `pizzaFactory` without arguments such as:

```
const pizza2 = pizzaFactory();
```

I hope that helps.